# How to see local traffic sent by a program to a local mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, capture

No matter what I do, I can't seem to make it connect. I can't decompile it; so it'd be very helpful to see what it sends.

MySQL Workbench logs *some* stuff but doesn't seem to have very verbose logging for every attempt to connect, for instance.

Comment: http://ethereal.com/ Not sure how human-readable the packets will be though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [MySQL Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy).

It sits between MySQL server and the client allowing you to monitor the communication.